# How to get back to an initial activity after moving through several more?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, gridview

I have an activity which can be accessed via different activities.
Like you have one activity containing a listview and the second containing a gridview and both shows the same data. When you click on an item a new activity with some details is shown. I need to somehow remember which activity was the initial one (with gridview or listview) so that I can set a button to redirect here. But it's not enough to just return to previous activity (like using finish() to close the current one), because there is a way to navigate among different objects from inside the details activity (I have a gridview on that screen). So I need to remember the initial view during moving through the details activity for various number of times.
Is there a way?

EDIT: omg why so many downvotes? At least tell me why it is so stupid, I'm learning coding for Android for 2 weeks how am I supposed to know everything??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like it would best be solved by using two [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) within the same `Activity`

Comment: ok thanks for a somewhat constructive reply, I'm gonna learn more about fragments since I've never used them before, I'm learning coding for Android for just 2 weeks...

Comment: I'm obviously asking dumb questions here, but I'll try it again not to do something stupid again.
do you mean 2 fragments for the view of all items or fragment to display details please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bundle object to pass data to the new activity (B) so you could know wich activity (listView or gridView) had started it.

In activity B:

```
private static final String ACTIVITY_TYPE = "activity_type";

public static Intent createIntent(Context context,String activityType)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString(ACTIVITY_TYPE,activityType);
    intent.putExtras(b);
    return intent;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String activityType;
    if (b != null)
    {
        activityType = b.getString(ACTIVITY_TYPE);
    }
    //the calling activity didn't use the createIntent method and didn't provide the activity type 
    else
    {
        activityType = "some_default_type";
    }

    //save activity type to use later
    //rest of your code
}
```

In the calling activity:

```
Intent intent = ActivityB.createIntent(ActivityListView.this,"activity_list_view");
startActivity(intent);
```